# Table Rows are not shown inside the tbody tag

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am looking to insert rows to the table but
The rows are echoed but not displayed inside the table.

The HTML code of the project is:

```
<div class="container">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SN</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Parent</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="displayCategory">               
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

The main.js file of the project is:
It fetches data from the PHP file below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
manageCategory();
function manageCategory(){
    
    $.ajax({
      url: DOMAIN + "/includes/process.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: { manageCategory: 1 },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#displayCategory").html(data);
        alert(data);
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
  };
}
```

PHP code of the project is:

```
<?PHP
if (isset($_POST["manageCategory"])) {
    $m = new Manage();
    $result = $m->manageTableWithPagination('pdcts_categories', 1);
    $rows = $result['rows'];
    $pagination = $result['pagination'];
    if (count($rows) > 0) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $n = 0;
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo ++$n; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Category"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Parent"]; ?></td> 
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"> Active </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"> Edit </a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"> Delete </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
        }?>
        <!-- <tr><td colspan="5"><?php echo $pagination; ?></td></tr> -->
    <?php exit(); }
}?>
```

Comment: Any error inside browser console  ?

Comment: None in the console there

Comment: Inspect the source after you generate the rows. Does the table's HTML structure look correct?

Comment: Your php code should return the data to the ajax call, so collect the data in a var and return it.

Comment: You may also check ☑ if your css is not hiding tbody tag or id displayCategory

Comment: Unable to reproduce on a simplified example. However, copying the JS code from your question results in a syntax error because a closing parenthesis for the `ready()` handler is missing.

Comment: @Grumpy Producing output in an AJAX script is a valid way of transferring content over to JS. It should work as it is.

Comment: Aside from the issue, what does your `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: It shows the rows passed from the PHP file:

Comment: <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Electronics</td>
                    <td>Mobile Phones</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"> Active </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"> Edit </a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"> Delete </a>
                    </td>

Comment: the above code is not correct. It's missing the row closing tag: `</tr>`

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: The closing tag is there, I forgot to copy it. 
I use chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending data (insted of `html`) like so:

```js
$("#displayCategory").append(data);
```

note: check in the console that your php code is returning valid html (`<tr>` data)

Comment: Appending really shouldn't affect the outcome here.

Comment: I have already tried this, nothing works. 

Yeah, the console returns valid data.